# How to deal with bad smelling (smoking) co-student

Tags: collaboration, interpersonal-issues

For a graduate project I need to work together with a fellow student who smokes a lot (every time we take a break); the smell is really strong and actually distracts from the work at times. Some days we work from about 8am to 6pm together, which is quite a long time.

I'm not sure how to approach him about it, you can't really forbid someone to smoke, of course. Surely not for the duration of a whole day (I doubt someone who is addicted to it can go without for that long anyway). In a workplace setting, as ff524 mentioned, I might go to a manager, etc, but that is not always an option in academia.

In addition, I'm quite sure that he's unaware of this..

Comment: I would have a big bottle of Febreze (an odor-masking spray) and spray him before he came in to work with me. Smokers know they smell and they know the smell carries.

Comment: @RoboKaren: “Smokers know they smell and they know the smell carries.” – I wouldn’t be so sure about that. Most people (not only smokers) have an amazing ability to selectively not preceive certain unwelcome aspects of reality.

Comment: re: garlic. I'd bring gum or mints in that case. :) There's tolerance and then there's bring able to focus on the problem.

Comment: Contrary to popular opinion, smokers are human beings, spraying them with deodorant is disrespectful and idiotic. People can have a variety of odors that other people don't like to smell (example: dog smell). If the smoke smell is really more than a simple annoyance to you, discuss the matter like two decent human beings.

Comment: @CapeCode I would assume RoboKaren is being sarcastic and making a joke. Considering actually doing this would be considered assault.

Comment: @Compass in the context of the current anti-smokers campaign, anything is possible.

Comment: I was a pain in the ass when I was a grad student, so I might have done it. Now that I'm older and wiser, I'd find a conference room with a big table and sit on opposite ends.

Comment: [Here is the analogous question at Workplace.SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/621/17125), it may be helpful.

Comment: You can start eating fried fish for lunch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe the best thing to do is to be honest and tell him that the smell is very strong.

Engage him in a discussion about smoking and ask him whether he has any plans to quit. From my experience *every smoker wishes to quit*. Then tell him that the smell is strong and sometimes you can't focus because of it. Take into account that this is maybe the first experience for him to work in a lab. Later on, he would definitely be aware of this, such as a non-academic workplace.

**Things you can do:**

1. Try not to discuss or meet right after smoking.
2. Share gum with him.
3. Bringing air freshener to your office

In the end, there is nothing you can do if he's not willing to cooperate.

There are related questions discussing the same issue on [Workplace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=smoking) containing additional advice.

Comment: *ask him whether he has any plans to quit* how is this anyone else's business?

Comment: @CapeCode it is not. However, I think as they both are students (around similar age) and work together 10 hours daily they most likely have good relation and involve in discussions out of their work scope (*Did you see last night game?* ).

Comment: @CapeCode: It would seem to be the business of everyone whose performance is influenced by the smoking. As the OP feels the smell originating from the smoking "actually distracts [the OP] from the work at times", the OP could be said to belong to that set of people.

Comment: @seteropere Most of our discussions revolve around the work we're doing, even outside of it. We don't much discuss varia ^^